# What is the difference in meaning between 'nonchalant' and 'insouciant'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, etymology, connotation

OED defines them as:

> **nonchalant** *adjective* (of a person or manner) feeling or appearing casually calm and relaxed; not displaying anxiety, interest, or enthusiasm
>
> **insouciant** *adjective* showing a casual lack of concern; indifferent
>
> **blithe** *adjective* showing a casual and cheerful indifference considered to be callous or improper:
> *a blithe disregard for the rules of the road*;
> happy or joyous: *a blithe seaside comedy*

So, what would be the difference between say, "a *nonchalant* shrug" and
"an *insouciant* shrug"?

Also, what context are these words used in the following sentence:

> "I would live all my life in nonchalance and insouciance Were it not
> for making a living, which is rather a nouciance." Ogden Nash, poet
> (Hard Lines, 1931)

Also, what does 'nouciance' mean? Is it simply a play on words?

Last, but most important, what word would best fit the following situation:

> He was (nonchalant/insouciant/blithe) about the poor living conditions of the animals in his farm.

Comment: I'd stick with indifferent, but use the correctly paired preposition / particle: _He was indifferent to the poor living conditions of the animals in his farm._

Comment: Insouciant sounds a little more negative to me than nonchalant. For your last question, it depends on what nuance you want; the first two are fine. 'Blithe' sounds funny in that construction like that to me: 'X is blithe' is uncommon I think, but 'blithely' more common...this calls for an nGram!!

Answer (score 4):

***Some background on the difference between 'nonchalant' and 'insouciant'***

Before focusing on the meanings of the two words, let's take a look at the Ngram chart for *nonchalant* (blue line) versus *insouciant* (red line):

[image]

According to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*, *nonchalant* entered English (directly from French) circa 1734, whereas *insouciance*—the noun form of *insouciant*—arrived (also directly from French) in 1799. The Ngram chart suggests that *nonchalant* has been several times more common than *insouciant* in published English texts for the past 150 years or so. Even so, I was somewhat surprised that the *Eleventh Collegiate* doesn't give *insouciant* a separate entry. Here are its entries for *nonchalance* and *nonchalant*:

> **nonchalance** *n* (1678) : the state or quality of being nonchalant
>
> **nonchalant** *adj* {F[rench] fr[om] pr[esent] p[articiple] of *nonchaloir* to disregard, fr[om] *non*- + *chaloir* to concern, fr[om] L[atin] *calēre* to be warm —more at LEE} (ca. 1734) : having an air of easy unconcern or indifference ***syn*** see COOL — **nonchalantly** *adv*

And here is its entry for *insouciance*:

> **insouciance** *n* {F[rench], fr[om] *in*- + *soucier* to trouble, disturb, fr[om] O[ld] F[rench],fr[om] L[atin] *sollicitare* — more at SOLICIT} (1799) : lighthearted unconcern : NONCHALANCE — **insouciant** *adj* — **insouciantly** *adv*

The synonyms note under the entry for *cool* discusses a group of similar adjectives: *cool*, *composed*, *collected*, *unruffled*, *imperturbable*, and *nonchalant*. Considering that MW views *insouciance* as meaning "lighthearted unconcern: NONCHALANCE," The exclusion of *insouciant* from the cluster of synonyms allied with *cool* is surprising and disappointing. The note on *nonchalant* in the entry under cool reads as follows:

> NONCHALANT stresses an easy coolness of manner or casualness that suggests indifference or unconcern {a *nonchalant* driver}

This very much of a piece with the discussion of *nonchalant* in *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942):

> **Nonchalant** stresses an easy coolness of manner, or casualness that suggests, rather than necessarily implies, indifference or unconcern: it often connotes lightheartedness; as, "God...knows, if he is not as indifferent to mortals as the *nonchalant* deities of Lucretius" (*Byron*); "Dallying with a cigar, which he smoked *nonchalantly* as he sang (*T. E. Brown*); "He walked in a *nonchalant* fashion" (*D. H. Lawrence*).

Meriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms (1984) repeats its 42-year-older predecessor's entry almost word for word, except tht it drops the phrase "rather than necessarily implies" and replaces the T.E. Brown quotation with this one:

> at the back {of the ambulance}, haughty in white uniform, *nonchalant* on a narrow seat, was The Doctor—*Sinclair Lewis*

And yet the entry for *nonchalant* in *Webster's Fifth Collegiate Dictionary* (1936/1941) is quite different from the one that appears in *Webster's Ninth Collegiate Dictionary* (1983), which is identical to the entry (noted above) in the *Eleventh Collegiate*. Here is the *Fifth Collegiate*'s entry:

**nonchalant**, *adj*. ... Lacking in warmth of feeling, enthusiasm, or interest; indifferent; also, *Colloq[uial]*, casual and imperturbable.

The *Fifth Collegiate*'s entry for insouciance, meanwhile, contains this information:

> **insouciance**, *n*. ... Want of concern; indifference, esp[ecially] as an attitude of mind

In effect, such difference as remains between nonchalant and insouciant in 1941 seems to reflect the difference in their French roots—*nonchalance* suggesting indifference through a lack of warmth or concern, and *insouciance* suggesting indifference through an absence of care or troubledness. The meanings are clearly very close, in any case.

One reference work that does provide discussions of both *nonchalant* and *insouciant* is S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word: A Modern Guide to Synonyms* (1968). But rather unexpectedly, Hayakawa assigns the two words to different synonym groups: *nonchalant* lands in a group headed by *flippant*; and *insouciant* falls into group under *jaunty*.

Here are the relevant comments from these two discussions:

> **flippant, casual, flip, fresh, nonchalant, sassy, smart, wise** These words are all all used to describe particular kinds of attitudes, speech, and behavior. ... Unlike [*flippant*, *flip*, *sassy*, and *fresh*], **casual** and **nonchalant** can be neutral or even complimentary in tone. Both words indicate a lack of concern, interest, or excitement: a *casual* air; a *nonchalant* approach to business problems. *Nonchalant*, however, may suggest an attempt to be disciplined or detached: All during the meeting, Mr. Jessup maintained his *nonchalant* manner, even when the shouting and arguing were at their height.
>
> ...
>
> **jaunty, chipper, debonair, insouciant** These words are used to describe a brisk unworried, self-assured person or the way in which he acts. ... **Insouciant** translates literally from the French to mean without care; it also suggests gaiety of manner and sophistication: the *insouciant* young bohemians who travel from on party to another without a thought for tomorrow.

Here again, the distinction between the two words seems to rest primarily on a perceived difference between lack of concern (*nonchalant*) and lack of care (*insouciant*). Hayakawa seems to think that the former reflects an attitude while the latter reflects a spirit; I'm not at all persuaded that he is right.

---

***My answers to the poster's specific questions***

With regard to the poster's specific questions, I offer these answers:

**1.** To judge from the foregoing discussions of the meanings of *insouciant* and *nonchalant*, the difference between "a nonchalant shrug" and "an insouciant shrug" might be imperceptible to an objective viewer, although we might expect the insouciant shrug to be a bit more vigorous (because it expresses a carefree attitude) than the nonchalant shrug (which is likely to be muted by the shrugger's lack of concern for whatever has prompted the shrug.

**2.** Ogden Nash seems to be using the words *nonchalance* and *insouciance* without a great deal of regard for their overlap in meaning. He is aiming for comic effect and so is happy to use two words where one would convey the essential notion of cucumberish imperturbability.

**3.** Nash uses *nouciance* as a ludicrous spelling for *nuisance*, nothing more. A similar joke spelling for the sake of a rhyme appears in his famous short poem, "If called by a panther/ Don't anther."

**4.** As for the sentence "He was (nonchalant/insouciant/blithe) about the poor living conditions of the animals in his farm," I wholeheartedly agree with Edwin Ashworth's comment (beneath the question) that none of the three named options is as suitable as *indifferent* would be and that a change in preposition from *about* to *to* would further improve the sentence:

> He was **indifferent to** the poor living conditions of the animals in his farm.

In my view, *indifferent* indicates a level of coldness toward potential suffering that the other terms—with their emphasis on disposition (*blithe*), attitude (*nonchalant*), or spirit (*insouciant*)—are ill equipped to convey.

Answer (score 1):

It is play on words, and in several ways.

- First, he’s combining the two words *nonchalance* and *insouciance* into ****nouciance***, which is really just an unusual spelling of what is supposed to recall *nuisance*.
- Second, he’s chosen these two French imports because they are negatives that have no corresponding positive forms in English, meaning that there is no ****chalance*** to pair with *nonchalant* nor any ****souciance*** to pair with *insouciance*.

Comment: Do you have any answer to the difference between the two themselves?

Answer (score 0):

**One** - Ogden Nash, master of letters as he was, was being clever & deliberately rhyming insouciance with nuisance (nouciance).

**Two** - I've personally battled with split differentials re insouciance and nonchalance myself in a couple of my books (this name is one of my many pseudonyms) and I found that using nonchalance best-described ambivalence in decision making and insouciance was more of a care-free attitude adapted in general life. I realize this is my own interpretation but it's one I discussed with my publisher and I ended up bringing her around (she was far from nonchalant in accepting my insouciant manuscripts.)

Answer (score 0):

**Nonchalant** implies having no real interest or opinion or trying to appear so. Insouciant connotes a touch of attitude, making a conspicuous show of indifference.

In your sentence, if you mean to say that the person is genuinely indifferent to the living conditions of the animals, nonchalant is the more appropriate word.